# Can't write to smbclient-mounted network disk without sudo

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, network-drive

I mounted a network disk using

```
smbclient -L //network_disk -U MYDOMAIN/myuser
sudo mount.cifs -v //network_disk/G ~/G  --verbose -o user=myuser,domain=MYDOMAIN
```

After that, I can't for example `touch ~/G/temp10.txt` but can `sudo touch ~/G/temp10.txt`
I tried to use `sudo chown -R $USER ~/G`. I waited about 5 minutes and it was still not finished. It seems the network disk is too large (24 TB) for me to use this function. Also, I tried `sudo chgrp myuser ~/G`. It didn't help.
I want to know how to access this network disk without sudo.

Also, if I use `mount.cifs -v //network_disk/G ~/G  --verbose -o user=myuser,domain=MYDOMAIN` I have an error

```
mount.cifs: permission denied: no match for /home/myuser/G found in /etc/fstab
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what happens when you cange your mount expressions to this:

```
sudo mount.cifs -v //network_disk/G ~/G  --verbose -o user=myuser,domain=MYDOMAIN,uid=myuser
```

CIFS mounts set the owner to root with write access only to root. uid=myuser replaces root with you.

The myuser in "user=myuser" is the user name the server is expecting.
The myuser in "uid=myuser" is your local Linux user name.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked

Comment: dang this worked - deluge can write again yay!